# xpages register a anonymous user to names.nsf with login name and email

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

**Case:** Create a web application to register user through the Name.nsf on the server.

userA

userB

means there have 2 database related.

First database: Anonymous(web) allow to key in there information through the database.

Second database: Names.nsf

First database with "full" access user must be allow to create a user in the names nsf or create an email address for user!

**Question**

Do i just need to link the names.nsf in server view ($VIMPeopleByLastName) and create document of those web-user?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation regarding Directory Assistance. It sounds like that would be the approach required.

Answer (score 0):

It's been along time since I did things with the NAB (exchange, exchange everywhere) however if I recall this is pretty straightforward.... Previously, via an xpage, I got the user to fill out a username and a few details, then when you submit, call a lotuScript agent that goes off and create's the account in the NAB? I believe it used to check user didnt exist already, set the htttpPassword field, the change date to now, username, company, email address etc - The agent can be run with the rights of a user who has access to write to the NAB also. It then creates the account, generates a password, and used to email a link where the user would then go to set their own password

Answer (score 0):

I found solution using notes agent to update it. I not sure xpages javascript way of writing it. Below is my script of using NotesRegistration : RegisterNewUser

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Initialize
'   this agent use on [register] button locate on [request form] xpages

Dim s As New NotesSession, db As NotesDatabase, a As NotesAgent
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Set db = s.Currentdatabase
Set a = s.Currentagent
Set doc = s.Documentcontext     '   uidoc 

Dim certid As String 'full path of cert id
Dim certpasswd As String
Dim OU As String
Dim lastname As String
Dim firstname As String
Dim middleinit As String
Dim usrIdpath As String
Dim mailsvr As String
Dim mailfile As String
Dim userpasswd As String
Dim internetpath As String

Dim depvw As NotesView, depdoc As NotesDocument
Set depvw = db.Getview("Department sort by dept")
Set depdoc = depvw.Getdocumentbykey(doc.Dept(0), True)
If Not depdoc Is Nothing Then
    certid = depdoc.IdPath(0)                                       '   full path of cert id
    certpasswd = depdoc.IdPassword(0)                               '   Cert id password(password)
    OU = depdoc.Dept(0)                                             '   Application (department to register)
    lastname= doc.SelectMail(0)                                     '   current document selected mail (person)
    firstname = ""      '                                            [din't used]
    middleinit = ""                                                 '   [din't used]
    usrIdpath = depdoc.DptIdStor(0) +doc.SelectMail(0)+ ".id"       '   user path
    mailsvr = depdoc.MailSvr(0)                                     '   mail svr
    mailfile = depdoc.MailLocation(0)+doc.SelectMail(0)             '   Mail\person
    userpasswd= depdoc.UserPassword(0)                              '   User password
    internetpath = doc.SelectMail(0)+depdoc.InternetPath(0)         '   mail address

End If

Dim reg As New NotesRegistration
Dim dt As Variant
dt = DateNumber(Year(Today)+1, Month(Today), Day(Today))

reg.RegistrationServer = mailsvr        '"CN=ServerOne/O=dev"
reg.CreateMailDb = True                 '
reg.CertifierIDFile = certid            '"C:\IBM\Domino\data\office.id"
reg.Expiration = dt
reg.IDType = ID_HIERARCHICAL
reg.MinPasswordLength = 1               ' password strength
reg.IsNorthAmerican = True
reg.OrgUnit = OU                        '"Application"
reg.RegistrationLog = "log.nsf"
reg.UpdateAddressBook = True
reg.StoreIDInAddressBook = True
reg.MailInternetAddress =  internetpath '"person@devsv1.pcs.com.my"


Call reg.RegisterNewUser(lastname, _    ' last name
usridpath, _                            '"C:\IBM\Domino\data\ +name+.id"    ' file to be created
mailsvr, _                              '"CN=ServerOne/O=dev"               ' mail server
firstname, _                            '                                   ' first name
middleInit, _                           '                                   ' middle initial
certpasswd, _                           '"office"                           ' certifier password
"", _                                   ' location field
"", _                                   ' comment field
mailfile, _                             '"mail\person.nsf"                 ' mail file
"", _                                   ' Forwarding domain
userpasswd, _                           '"password", _                   ' user password
NOTES_DESKTOP_CLIENT)                   ' user type


End Sub
```

Comment: If the users only need access from the web, using the registration class is over kill since it creates the uses as Notes users with ID files, etc. Web users will not need that unless they are iNotes users also.

Comment: Yes, they are notes user when they go back to office to use their notes client.